# How to check if cell contains TWO strings in VBA

Tags: string, vba

How can I check if a cell contains two separate strings in a cell? I tried:

```
ElseIf InStr(1, UCase(testVal), UCase("goku"), 1) And InStr(1, UCase(testVal), UCase("vegeta"), 1) Then
            Worksheets("Export Worksheet").Cells(i, 18).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = "4"
```

However, this does not work...

If I use

```
ElseIf InStr(1, UCase(testVal), UCase("goku"), 1) & InStr(1, UCase(testVal), UCase("vegeta"), 1) Then
            Worksheets("Export Worksheet").Cells(i, 18).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = "4"
```

It will highlight the row if "goku" OR "vegeta" are in the cell. However, I need BOTH values to be in the cell.

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the result of InStr to be great than 0.  Also use "And" not "&"

```
ElseIf InStr(1, UCase(testVal), UCase("goku"), 1) > 0 AND InStr(1,     UCase(testVal), UCase("vegeta"), 1) > 0 Then
        Worksheets("Export Worksheet").Cells(i, 18).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = "4"
```

Comment: The "&" will concatenate the values returned from InStr.